# facebook api v2.0 get friends picture and birthday

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-javascript-sdk

Developer update and I have a problem, I need friends picture and birthday but friends data array is not contained Object Fields birthday and picture, data contain only id and name.

It is not a permission problem, I have all permission but it does not work.

When I open Graph Explorer, select friends query is "me? fields=friends" friends don't have Fields.

What is the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new V2.0 API you must use the `user_friends` permission. It will only return the friends that also use your app, and only the name and ID. So not the complete list of friends.

As you can read in the V2.0 changelog, all other friends_* permissions are removed. Among which, the birthday and picture.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

If you want the profile picture, you can use `/me/taggable_friends` or `/me/invitable_friends`. That will return a bit more info.